# Adding button to right column of grid in Odoo form view

Tags: odoo

How can I add a button to the right-hand column within a form view in Odoo 10? For example, I am extending the `sale.order.form` view with the following fields:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@name='carrier_selection']" position="after">

    <field name="x_shipping_method_id" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>

    <field name="x_shipping_cost"/>

    <field name="x_staff_notes" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_staff_notes', '=', False)]}"/>

    <field name="x_custom_products" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_custom_products', '=', False)]}"/>

    <field name="x_is_custom_products_acknowledged" invisible="1"/>

    <button name="434" type="action" string="Acknowledge Custom Products" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('x_custom_products', '=', False),'&amp;',('x_custom_products', '!=', False), ('x_is_custom_products_acknowledged', '=', True)]}"/>

</xpath>
```

This results in the new fields being added in a grid with the labels on the left, and the values on the right. I want the button element to be added to the right-hand column of this grid. Currently it gets placed beneath the labels, in the left-hand column, but I would like it underneath the values, in the right-hand column. Is this possible with Odoo?

Here is a doctored screenshot to try and demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish. I just want the button to be in a new row, but aligned in the right column, with the values above it.
[image]

Comment: See I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to display only value but not the label then you can do something like that,

```
<field name="x_shipping_cost" nolabel="1" />
```

And then you can print label

```
<label for="x_shipping_cost" />
```

By this way your value print first and then label will be printed to the right.

However I didn't get more idea what you want to do actually, so I have just explain you what you can do to print value in left and title in right. If you need anything else then please clarify.

**Solution** : You can achieve it by just adding empty label

```
<label string=""/> 
<button name="434" type="action" string="Acknowledge Custom Products" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('x_custom_products', '=', False),'&amp;',('x_custom_products', '!=', False), ('x_is_custom_products_acknowledged', '=', True)]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to print the button element in the right hand column. So the fields above the button should print as normal, label on the left, button on the right, but then I want the button element at the end to print on the right, underneath the values. Does that make sense? Also, I just realized I had my lefts and rights reversed in one part of the question. I edited the question so please re-read it just to make sure you have the information correct.

Comment: Can you please give me an example ? with small screen shot if possible.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the original question. Does that help?